# Using 'retrofit' library response has null fields

Tags: retrofit

I'm calling a REST service using retrofit. The REST service returns a JSON message. The Java response object has null fields values.

Setup Code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
        .create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
        .setEndpoint(myEndpoint).build();

restAdapter.setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL);
SomeService someService = restAdapter
        .create(SomeService.class);
```

The service interface:

```
public interface SomeService {
    @POST("/firstParam/{firstParam}/secondParam/{secondParam}")
    MyResponse callService(@Path("firstParam") String firstParam,
            @Path("secondParam") String secondParam, @Body MyRequest request);
}
```

The Response Pojo:

```
class MyResponse {
    private String paramOne;
    private String paramTwo;
    private String action;
    private String status;

    //getters and setters
}
```

But when I call:

```
MyResponse response = someService.callService("one","two",request);
```

the fields in response are still null.

I had to use a custom JsonDeserializer to get it working but I'm thinking this is standard stuff it shouldn't need a JsonDeserializer.

Can you suggest an approach that saves me from using a JsonDeserializer ?

Comment: It may be easier to help you if we could get some example response JSON...

Comment: @david.mihola Thanks here it is {
  "paramOne": "456",
  "paramTwo": "123",
  "action": "actionOne",
  "status": "success"
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)` when building your `Gson` object.

Accordingly, Gson will now try to map the Java field name `paramOne` to a value with key `ParamOne` in your JSON. But no such value exists - it is called `paramOne`, just like in the Java class.

So, try this:

- leave out the `setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)`. (You can still use `@SerializedName` in cases where you need a different mapping from JSON key to Java field name.)